# synchronized in thread concepts of java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

When I try to execute the piece of code, I am getting output like `12221121212121221212`. When I declare the method as `synchronized`, it should not allow the other thread to take over the control

```
package com.test;

public class TestProject extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.print(getName());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TestProject myProject = new TestProject();
        TestProject myProject1 = new TestProject();
        myProject.setName("1");
        myProject1.setName("2");
        myProject.start();
        myProacject1.start();
    }
}
```

So, how do I alter the code to get a output of **11111111112222222222** or **22222222221111111111** in sequential format?

Answer (score 6):

You are synchronizing on `this`, i.e. on the `TestProject` object. Since you have two separate objects, you have two separate locks. Consequently, both threads can enter the `synchronized` section irrespective of what the other thread is doing.

To synchronize across instances of `TestProject` you need a static lock:

```
public class TestProject extends Thread {

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            ...
```

Comment: Note: the lock is outside the loop. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That's right. The real issue is that there are two separate locks so there is no synchronization happening across threads. Once that's fixed, the OP will get the desired output (11111111112222222222 or 22222222221111111111).

Comment: seems like even the above program give the same kind of output which is not in a sequential format

Answer (score 1):

Java uses biased locking by default.  This means a lock will favour the last thread to access a lock.  If you consider that one thread can start, run and finish before the other even starts I would expect you get one thread running to completion before the other starts most of the time.

I have just noticed you lock outside the loop.  This will guarantee you also run one thread to completion before the other starts.

This is how you can enforce fair alternation of threads.

```
public class TestProject implements Runnable {
    private final Lock lock;
    public TestProject(Lock lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
        new Thread(new TestProject(lock), "1").start();
        new Thread(new TestProject(lock), "2").start();
    }
}
```

can print

```
12121212121212121212
```

Note: if you make the lock non-fair you can get (change the true to false)

```
11111111112222222222
```

Note: if you want fair alternation between two tasks, it much simpler to use one thread and a loop.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // task 1
        System.out.print("1");
        // task 2
        System.out.print("2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use join method on myProject1 so that it waits for the other thread to finish

Answer (score 0):

these are the following method that can be used to achieve synchronization among the thread

1). use a static global lock and pass that object variable as argument to the synchronized block

2). use join()

3). create a instance for the Object class and pass that as an argument to the synchronized block like this `Object myObject = TestProject.class` now pass myObject to the synchronized block

using either of the above ways we can achieve synchronization